# GLIDE - Docusign API User Authentication Error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on an API from Glide to Docusign and I'm getting an error. I've successfully run the API in Postman. I can see the full request in Postman and I wanted to compare it to the GLIDE request I'm making.

Does anyone know if there is a way to see the GLIDE API request?

Not that it will help much, but here is the error I'm getting from GLIDE: Call API:

> {"errorCode":"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"One or both of Username and Password are invalid. invalid_request"}

Confirmed that my developer account is authenticating properly by successfully running the API in Postman.

Here is the format (without the values) of the successful postman URL: `{{baseUrl}}/{{apiVersion}}/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes`

Comment: Please update (edit) your question to add more information. Which oauth flow are you using? Are you using an oauth library or code that you wrote? Help us help you...

Comment: Are you using the [Glide DocuSign integration](https://www.glideapps.com/docs/automation/integrations/docusign)? If so, contact Glide support for help.

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign Glide integration is only using production, whereas you created a developer account and used postman with the developer account.

If you want to build your own DocuSign glide integration then you should make sure that you follow the right way to obtain access tokens.

That means, if you chose Auth Code Grant, there are 2 things to do, first obtain a code, and then exchange it for an access token. The first part is done in the browser, and the second part is done using an API call, but not the userinfo call, that one assumes you already authenticated.